# how to get nstextfield from control:textView:doCommandBySelector

Tags: nstextfield

I have 6 textfield, and I want to know which field response to this method.
I can't transfer textView to textfield, what can I do ?

```
(BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control
   textView:(NSTextView *)textView
doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector{


NSLog(@"commandSelector : %@",NSStringFromSelector(commandSelector));
//insertTab:   -键入tab
//insertNewline:   -键入回车
//deleteBackward

MSSingleField *field = (MSSingleField *)textView;

if ([NSStringFromSelector(commandSelector) isEqualToString:@"deleteBackward:"]) 
{

    if (field.lastKeyView) {
        [field.lastKeyView becomeFirstResponder];
    }

}

return NO;
}
```

Comment: Don't call `becomeFirstResponder`. "Use the NSWindow makeFirstResponder: method, not this method, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly.".

Answer (score 1):

The `control` parameter is the text field.